# Find the total CPU usage on Ubuntu server version 20.10 without installing additional tools

Tags: server, cpu, 20.10, top

I need to find the total CPU(s) usage of the server without installing additional tools.

Do I understand correctly that the field `id` of the `top` command in `CPU(s)` line can help me with it?

Can I do `100 - {id} = {total CPU(s) usage}` to find the total CPU usage?

Comment: Yes you are correct, you can calculate based on the values shown in `top`.

Comment: @ArturMeinild thanks for the answer, just to clarify `id` is enough for it?

Comment: Yes I believe so.

Comment: This ( http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm ) may be the most fundamental interface in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

The `top` utility is an excellent option because it is available even on small Linux installations. You can even get rid of the math you mention.

While `top` is running, you can toggle SUMMARY AREA  options:

- Pressing <kbd>t</kbd> will let you switch between 4 modes. The second option will show your CPU load in the following format:

  ```
  abbreviated user/system and total % + bar graph
  ```

  The third number is the one that interests you.

I also like to use an additional toggle:

- Pressing <kbd>1</kbd> will let you see the utilization of every single core.

**Note:** While you can run `top -1`, I have not found out in man pages how to run `top -t`. Therefore I use the <kbd>t</kbd> toggle once `top` is running.

Comment: Instead of pressing `t` (or any other toggle) every time you use `top`, you can save your current `top` configuration by pressing `W` (`Shift`+`w`). The configuration will be saved to `~/.config/procps/toprc`. To restore the default configuration, just delete the `~/.config/procps/toprc` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor your total CPU usage using `htop`. To install `htop` run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install htop
```

Then open `htop` by running:

```
htop
```

You can now see the total CPU usage.

[image: htop running]

Comment: Sorry, did not mention that I can't install additional tools on the server

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the CPU usage using the `vmstat` command. Run this command in the terminal, as follows:

```
vmstat
```

[image: vmstat running]